# How to keep consistency in a C++ function called in 2 places if it is manually inlined in only one of the places

Tags: c++, macros, inline

I got a Linux C++ program design problem in my job .

A function f() is called in two places. It has been declared as inline.

In place one, f() is called 10000 times, we need to do manual inline (copy f() body to its caller) to reduce overhead of calling it. The benefits have been confirmed by results.

In place two, f() is only called once for a purpose different from place one.

For further work me may make some changes inside f(), if we do inline manually, it is required  to make the same changes in f() body in place two so that f() in place 1 and 2 are always exactly same.

it is hard to make synchronization between place 1 and 2 in this way.

We do not want to use macro because we need to use gdb for debug.

`__attribute__ ((always_inline))` is not supported on our system.

Comment: yes, it has, but we have to do inlining manually because the results have confirmed that it has benefits.

Comment: Is something wrong with your `inline` keyword?  How about `__attribute__(always_inline)` ?

Comment: Why are you manually inlining it instead of letting the compiler do it with the `inline` keyword (or if need be, something like the [`always_inline` attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2//gcc/Function-Attributes.html)?

Comment: we just use inline keyword, but its performance is not so good as manual inlining. the results have confirmed this.

Comment: @Ben, __attribute__(always_inline) can 100% assure that it will be inlined ?

Comment: Write the function's body as a macro and apply the macro in the two places where it's needed.

Comment: If you are debugging code you probably do not have any optimizations enabled which would explain why you did not see any performance gain. As others have said use `__attribute__ ((always_inline))` to guarantee inlining even without optimizations.

Comment: It's actually `__attribute__ ((always_inline))` but yes, this will force an inline function to be inlined even if the compiler wouldn't normally inline it.

Comment: @runnerfrank well, not *guarantee*. gcc tends to stop at an instruction count (size). it's also can't inline a recursive function for obvious reasons. anyways; just use the attribute instead of a macro, those are both examples of problems you can easily fix, if you want to take the responsibility from the compiler in this case.

Comment: You say `f()` is "declared inline". But more importantly *is its body visible* at the point where it's called? A simple program example that demonstrates the performance gain by manually inlining would be extremely helpful as well.

Comment: @justin : Recursive functions can be inlined as long as they're tail-recursive.

Comment: @ildjarn i know, but good point. +1

Comment: @Ben and Paul : __attribute__ ((always_inline)) is not supported on our system.

Comment: @runnerfrank, what weird system is that?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility which would generate somewhat unintuitive code but would allow the same piece of code to be used in both inlined and not inlined version would be as follows (it works if there is exactly one place where the function needs to be inlined).

Suppose `a()` is the piece of code you want to have in either inlined or non-inlined form, and `b()` is the function inside which an inlined version of `a()` should be embedded. Make use of C++ templates and parametrize `b()` with a `bool`ean parameter, called e.g. `JUST_A`. Now, your function `b()` could look like this:

```
if (!JUST_A) {
    //do something
}
b()
if (!JUST_A) {
    //do something more
}
```

Since the template mechanism generates code for each parametrisation separately, the boolean parameter will get optimized out and you will end up with one variant (for `JUST_A==false`) which does:

```
//do something
b()
//do something more
```

and another which does only

```
b()
```

(for `JUST_A==true`). Depending on whether you call `a<true>()` or `a<false>()` you will run one piece of code or the other.

You can check in your program's disassembly if this actually works, but it should. Still, I don't think this is nice code and would prefer some variant of forced inlining that others have suggested for code readability if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Offer the function twice. The first function is implemented inline in a header, the second is implemented in a cpp file calling the inline function.

```
// function_inline.h
inline void function_inline()
{
   // implementation
}

// function.h
void function();

// function.cpp
#include "function.hpp"
#include "function_inline.hpp"
void function() { function_inline(); }
```

The regular code would call `function()` but in places where you want the function to be inlined, `function_inline()` can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Use the macro. When you want to debug, copy the body out of the macro into the code, debug it, then switch back to the macro when done. Unless the situation is a bit unusual, you shouldn't need to step through that code that many times to get it right.

Alternatively, you could use a pre-processor alternative like [Cog](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/cog/) or a custom script to verify that the code stays the same. Basically, put a marker around the block in question in both files, and have something extract and compare. If they get out of sync, break the build.